# Subtracting formula in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

How do I subtract the amount in one cell, from the amount in another cell, in Google Spreadsheets? Do I use a formula to subtract? Can you tell me what is it?

Comment: Please share a dummy sheet that matches your use-case so we can have a look.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering but I have got it now.

Answer (score 3):

If the first value is in cell A1 and the second is in cell B1, and you want to show the result of the subtraction in cell C1, simply put in cell C1:

```
=A1-B1
```

It doesn't matter whether the values in either A1 or B1 were achieved with a simple value or a function.

Of course, your values need to be numbers for this to work.

Comment: Thank you for answering, but I must be doing something wrong? I am working with money values, does that matter? When I do that I get #VALUE! What does that mean?

Comment: It probably means something isn't a number. You should edit your question with a sample of the data you're working with, the stuff you've already tried, and exactly what errors you're getting.

Comment: The value in the first cell is $87,000.00 and the values in the cell I am subtracting from it is $6503.25 . Can this be done ale? And I get #VALUE! instead of the result.

Comment: Please edit your question to have all of the salient information. This site isn't built for a lot of back-and-forth troubleshooting. I'll bet you have the literal dollar signs in the cell instead of formatting as currency. The actual data should only be a number.

Comment: Thank you. I am very grateful for your help. I know it is nothing fancy but I appreciate all your kind help. I guess I do not know what I am doing yet. Now it gives me the formula..=E5-E21 instead of a result.   I will look somewhere else for my answers I am sorry to have bothered you.

Comment: It's not a bother; we're happy to help. You're just not giving us enough to go on. Comments are meant to request clarification or otherwise improve the post they're attached to, and are meant to be temporary. They shouldn't be used for back-and-forth discussion. That's why I keep asking you to edit your question, so that it has all the information for someone to be able to help you _and_, more importantly, when someone has a very similar situation they'll find an answer waiting for them.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have to go to a meeting, otherwise I would have suggested we go into [chat]. But there are a lot of people here who know a lot about Google Sheets who would be happy to help, but you need to give them the information they need up front.